# Limit WebBrowser from consuming too much memory

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control

I'm working on a project that involves WebBrowser control and have the following questions.

1. Is it possible to limit how much memory each instance of WebBrowser can consume?
2. Will enabling javascript increase WebBrowser memory consumption

Generally the idea is the project must use the WebBrowser so that i use less memory? Currently my App does exceed 145 mB of RAM usage when using WebBrowser control. If without using WebBrowser control it's only at maximum 50 mB.

Comment: [A couple of UX experts](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/SilverlightTV/Silverlight-TV-81-4-Great-Windows-Phone-UX-Tips) (at around 10m) recommend that you not use the control unless absolutely necessary, and that you send users to IE for web content.

Comment: Hahah i would've preferred that approach too :D
But it's a project requirement that i can't change?

Answer (score 1):

1) As far as i'm aware there's no API available to limit the RAM usage of an application/task - it's down to the OS's discretion and/or the functionality used by the application.

2) JavaScript is executed on the client, therefore it would be safe to assume there would be an increase in memory consumption.

I reccomend that you try and run your application through the performance profiler that comes with the latest SDK (7.1).

[Nokia](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Best_practices_for_delivering_apps_to_256_MB#Introduction) have a great set of articles covering memory usage, especially when encountering the 256MB devices.

Comment: What about introducing a soft fault when WebBrowser control exceeds a certain memory limit? When the soft fault or memory limit is triggered it will perform other clean-up logics?

Comment: You can't detect the RAM usage, it's not something that the OS/SDK exposes to the developer.

Comment: Maybe i'll just have to use the System.GC instead and set a certain treshold? Will it be feasible?

Comment: I reccomend you read the following MSDN blog post - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/abhinaba/archive/2011/06/14/wp7-mango-the-new-generational-gc.aspx